# Problema Angular Firestore - La funcion no retorna ningun valor

Tags: funciones, angular, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy teniendo un problema con la siguiente funcion.

```
 retornaCantidadActual(itemProducto) {

this.prodserv.getProdObservable(itemProducto).subscribe(dataprod => {
  const xxprod = dataprod;
  console.log('Funcion retornaCantidadActual =====>', xxprod[0].cantidadActual);
  return xxprod[0].cantidadActual;
});
```

}

Esta funcion se encuentra dentro de un componente de Angular 6 y esta utilizando firebase.  Como se ve el console log que esta dentro de la funcion me responde correctamente o sea esta tomando bien el valor.  El getProdObservable se encuentra en el servicio y retorna un observable con un unico registro que es el producto pasado por parametro a la funcion.  El problema esta cuando llamo a esta funcion desde otro lugar del programa ya que me retorna en console "undefined" y obviamente no toma ningun valor, pero me debería retornar el valor que muestra internamente, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.  Agradezco de antemano y envio un cordial saludo. Atte Marcelo.

Comment: al parecer es un tema con el observable pero no encuentro documentación sobre angularfirestore y la que he leído es bastante escueta si me pueden sugerir algún sitio donde encontrar documentación al respecto agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Si entiendo bien... Lo que quieres es que `retornaCantidadActual` retorne un `number` o  `string` ?

Comment: Si lo entiende bien,  lo que necesito en esta funcion es que retorne un número pero me retorna obviamente un observable,   lamentablemente no encuentro mucha info sonre firestore por lo que lo estoy intentando realizar de otra manera un poco mas complicada.  Aunque estoy seguro que existe algun método mas simple aunque como digo no encuentro documentación (tal vez es que angularfire2 es demasiado actual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**En resumen:** No podés obtener el numero de una sola, porque estás realizando un trabajo asíncrono. 
Tenés que usar el servicio que te retorna el `Observable` y subscribirte para hacer lo que necesites en el lugar que lo necesites.

---

No es que estés haciendo algo mal. Puede que no lo estés viendo de la manera correcta.

Debes tomar en cuenta que estas haciendo un trabajo asíncrono (que no tiene momento exacto de ejecución). Toda llamada por red es asíncrona y te tocará usar `Observable`, `Promise` o algun tipo de `callback` para cuando la llamada se resuelva. Debes comenzar a pensar de manera asíncrona (hay funciones que se van a ejecutar hasta dentro de un ratito, cuando la llamada sea resuelta).

Ya que estás trabajando con `angularfire2` te recomiendo leer acerca de `Observable`, pero en si `Firestore` trabaja también con `Promise` asi que puedes leer de eso también.

Para tu función, toma en cuenta que podés tener `Observable` y `Subcription`. Un `Observable` es un objeto al que te podés *subscibir* y obtener valores emitidos. Una `Subcription` es el objeto que contiene la función que se va a ejecutar cuando se emitan valores en el `Observable`.

Un `Observable` puede tener varias `Subcription` pegadas.

En tu función `retornaCantidadActual` lo que estas retornando en realidad es la `Subscription`.

Entonces lo que tenés que hacer es usar el Servicio que te retorna el `Observable` cuando lo necesites. No hay atajos para esto. Tenés que trabajar de manera asíncrona.

Comment: Por fin lo entiendo correctamente.  Muchas gracias por esta información es cierto lo estaba viendo como algo mas estatico y en realidad es 100% dinamica la data que recibo.  Me ha sido muy util esa respuesta por lo que voy a indagar mas acerca de los observables.  Tambien veo que en la funcion hay diferentes scopes, por lo que es logico que la información que necesito no se encuentre de la forma que la necesito.  Muchas gracias nuevamente,

Comment: Por otra parte,  no tengo idea de como dar por respondido o solucionado el tema.  Gracias por la ayuda!!